# Hp pavilion g6 doesn't boot from CD/DVD

Tags: boot, bios, livecd, hp-pavilion

I have a HP Pavilion g6 and I have burned a Linux Ubuntu 15.10 ISO to a DVD.
I entered the BIOS to change the boot option so that the computer boots the CD/DVD drive.
However, instead, it's always booting to Windows 7.
My CD drive is normal because it is displayed in Windows.
I have no idea what to do next, My BIOS chipset is running the Insyde H2O firmware which is version 03.72.05F.08.

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded Ubuntu 15.10 from `http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop`, extract it then burnt it to a DVD.

Comment: I must have burn the iso file directly into the DVD?

Comment: yes, in your answer these are extracted files. Right? I'm not using any downloaded software, I burn the DVD normally by right click on it.

Comment: Plz explain more because I'm new to these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your issue is you extracted the DVD contents and then burned them on DVD
2. Windows 7 Out of box DVD/CD software doesn't burn it as bootable

It needs to be a bootable DVD

Burning [bootable](http://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/iso-burner.htm) Disc on Windows 7 using power iso

http://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/iso-burner.htm

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by two things.

1. Either in the BIOS it is not set to boot from CD/DVD
2. The CD/DVD you're booting from does not contain a boot loader.

If you're sure the BIOS is setup correctly, then its likely something went wrong in burning the cd/dvd. You can test this by attempting to boot using another cd/dvd that you are sure to work. Just burning files to a cd/dvd is not enough. Normally these cd/dvd's are ISO and they have the bootloader embedded int hem.